# Can't find any documentation for Wamp64

Tags: wampserver

I can't find any documentation for Wamp64 - I'm looking e.g. for a documentation for /tasks CLI switch and I can't seem to find any. On [their page](http://www.wampserver.com/), at least English version, documentation isn't even mentioned. Their sourceforge page also doesn't seem to mention it.

Is there anything resembling proper documentation anywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there is nothing consistent. There is only forum, but I failed to register despite trying few times using different accounts.